# How convert Drawing.Color to Drawing.Brush, Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, colors, brush

How to Convert from `'System.Drawing.Color'` to `'System.Drawing.Brush'` ?

This cast does not work.

```
(Brush)colorDialog1.Color;
```

I have a color dialog, and I need to pick the color from it and use as `Brush` color

Comment: This video having a clear explanation but in Tamil - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oyGE_9haGyg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to choose a specific type of `Brush`, most common is `SolidBrush`:

```
using (Brush brush = new SolidBrush(colorDialog1.Color))
{
    // perform operations
}
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983677(v=vs.71).aspx for a list of available brushes.